# Create a date X years later than today

Tags: macros

I am trying to create a date X years later than `\today`. My dates have the following format : `dd/mm/yyyy`. I tried the `advdate` package, yet when the month is in [1-9] range, it returns the number of the month without a leading '0', i.e. the 18th February 2011 is displayed as 18/2/2011. Any way to get that leading 0 ?

I thought about doing a `if/else` statement, but it seems a bit dirty for such an easy task.

Answer (score 15):

You can load the `datetime` package and declare

```
\ddmmyyyydate
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{advdate}

\begin{document}

\ddmmyyyydate
\AdvYear{10}

\today

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]